# Using deep learning for time series prediction with uncertain time series window size!

Tags: deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I'm new in area of deep learning and I am trying to use deep learning to do prediction on machine generated log data gathered as stream of data.

I have seen [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short_term_memory) an how it can be helpful to train RNN with some understanding of time series [Sequence to sequence learning with neural networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3215), but they had simple definition of how long is their time window. The problem is, I am not sure what should be the proper window size of logs that I need to push to LSTM before feeding to RNN. Can someone elaborate how should I treat this problem:

- I am trying to find proper window size of log data according to their context?
- Is RNN actually a proper general model in here?